# JInternalFrame not change size

Tags: java, swing

Java 1.8.

I want to chnage size of my **JInternalFrame**.

Here code:

Here main frame:

```
public class MainScreenView extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        currentInternalFrame = new WelcomeInternalFrame(this);
        addInternalFrame(currentInternalFrame);
        setContentPane(desktop);
}
```

Here my internalFrame:

```
public class WelcomeInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {
    public WelcomeInternalFrame(Frame owner) {
        super("Title", false, true);
        this.owner = owner;
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But **WelcomeInternalFrame**  show maximize to whole screen. But I need size 500, 300

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. The code you posted wouldn't compile.

Comment: I found problem. I use `internalFrame.setMaximum(true)`. After remove this line the problem is gone.